Testing my React-Native app Offline/Online with Network Link Conditioner
I put you in context, I'm developing an React-Native app to send forms to a database, users can submit forms offline, when then connection is reactivated the form is sent, there are several steps in the forms, each steps is sent one by one.
My problem: I would like to activate/deactivate the connection while I'm filling in my form and keep the connection for debugging, but unfortunately when I activate "100% Lost" in Network Link Conditioner on my device, I loose the debug on Xcode.
I have already tried to modify my code to allow me to connect/disconnect, but unfortunately when I save the whole application is reloaded (hot reload) and I don't want that.
Do you have any solution ?
Thanks in advance
